# Cake PHP 3: How can I populate inputs from session?

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm trying to develop a simple edit form on Cake PHP 3 and I want to populate them from Session.

How can I do this?

**edit.ctp:**

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-5  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Edit</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

            <?php $nome = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.nome');

            echo  $this->Form->input('nome', array('id' => 'nome'), array('value' => $nome)); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email' ,array('id' =>'email')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'), array('id' => 'password')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Alterar', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What actually your problem, you are not getting Auth name or unable to apply edit ? Is it your nome or name field ?

Comment: Problem already solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$this->Form->input('nome', array('id' => 'nome'), array('value' => $nome));
```

With

```
$this->Form->input('nome', array('id' => 'nome','value' => $nome));
```

The standard cakephp form input syntax is

```
Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::input(string $fieldName, array $options =[])
```

Please check this for the rest of the fields also.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much! I'm new on CakePHP. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

same like edit action, just point id to **Auth User id**.

```
public function edit(){
     $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
     $user = $this->Users->get($id);
     //rest of your code here
}
```